# making specific buttons enabled while the gridview is disabled

Tags: asp.net, button, gridview

I have select buttons in the 1st column of my gridview for each of the rows.

what code should I use so
 I can only make the select buttons enabled while the gridview is initially disabled? 
and when the select button of the specific row has been clicked, it should  make the row enabled while the others are still disabled.

thank you so much for answering .

Comment: You need to put what you have tried so far in your question. You should also put some html in support of your question.

Comment: sorry i'm just new here... i'm still learning in using stackoverflow =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initially, to disable the GridView controls other than select button. You should disable all the controls one by one. If you disable a parent control, all child controls are automatically disabled. So If you only write **GridView1.Enabled=False**, whole gridview is disable including the select buttons. So you should enable and disable all controls manually.
To Enable the controls on Select button click, you go to RowCommand Event of the GridView.
And You check for the following:

```
    protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {

        if (e.CommandName == "Select")
        {
           //Enable any controls here
        }
    }
```

Comment: I tried to put my btn_select.enabled = true inside the code but it said that 'Ulit._Default.btn_Select(object, System.EventArgs)' is a 'method', which is not valid in the given context